# How do you simulate "sudo su <user>" in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a server where my user is able to sudo to the root user without a password, and then the root user can sudo to a third user without a password.  However, my user cannot sudo directly to the third user without a password.

Ansible's [become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html) directive uses sudo in the traditional manner, i.e. the one that requires prompting for my password.

I've tried putting `become_user: root` on a block and `become_user: <other-user>` on a task inside that block, but it appears Ansible overrides the block's definition, rather than nesting the sudo calls as I hoped.

Note: this question has also been asked [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47354108/120999), but since there's no solution I figured I would repost it here, which I think is the better site for it.

Comment: `my user cannot sudo directly to the third user without a password` - is that under ansible or directly in the shell?

Comment: @DanCornilescu In general as per sudoers configuration.

Comment: Maybe `sudo "sudo -u target_user command"` as command ?

Comment: @Xiong Chiamiov, did you find a workaround that worked for you ? I have the exact same problem :(

Answer (score 2):

I met the same situation. I have `login1` for my machine, passwordless sudo and `login2`, under which I should perform some actions. I did not solve it by ansible means. But I made such a workaround:

```
- name: "Install nvm"
  shell: sudo -u buildkite-agent bash -c "<my commands to be performed on behalf of buildkite-agent>"
  become: true
```

Such a case:

```
- name: "Install nvm"
  shell: sudo -u buildkite-agent <my commands to be performed on behalf of buildkite-agent>
  become: true
```

do not change home to `buildkite-agent`'s home, i.e. uses `/root` as home.

Answer (score 1):

Become super user at the play level and become another user at the task level:

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:

    - file:
        path: /tmp/test
        state: touch
      become_user: www-data
```

Validation:

```
$ ls -l /tmp | grep test
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    0 Mär 10 14:08 test
```

For very simple cases, a workaround like the following could also help, but this doesn't really scale, as you cannot use ansible modules with this strategy:

```
- name: test
  command: "sudo -u www-data whoami"
  become: true
```

Output (extract): `"stdout": "www-data"`

Comment: I tried your first suggestion (as well as a similar thing with a `block`), but it appears Ansible overrides the commands rather than nesting them (so it essentially replaces `sudo -u root` with `sudo -u www-data`, rather than nesting them to create `sudo -u root sudo -u www-data`).  I think that manual adjustments using command/shell and careful permissioning with the files module is the only way this is possible currently in Ansible.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov, strange, that worked for me (as you can see from the `ls -l /tmp` command). I am using ansible `2.4.2.0`. But, don't you have passwordless sudo for your `ansible_user`?

Comment: The ansible_user has passwordless sudo to the root account, but not to the tertiary account (`www-data` in your example).

Answer (score 0):

What I did that worked for me :

```
- name: launch pg_ctl start
  command: "su <USER> -l -c '<COMMAND>'"
  become: yes
  become_exe: sudo
```

PS : With `su -l`, it automatically load the `.bash_profile` and not the `.bashrc`

Answer (score -1):

For example you want to create a file you can use :

```
 name: Create file
 shell: "touch abc"
 become_user: <username>
 become: yes
```

This is equivalent to ::
sudo su username -c "touch abc"

Comment: No, it's equivalent to "sudo -u username", which as stated in the question is slightly but importantly different.

Comment: When you run the above mentioned Ansible, the file abc will be created by user mentioned in the username variable

Comment: Right, but you're missing the main point of the question, which is that the sudoers configuration does not allow the default ansible user to sudo directly to the final user.